# How can I bind multiple properties on the same WPF control?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I am able to bind my datasource to the textblock for the display text.  However I would like to set the Fontweight to bold if the value of the checkbox **foo** is checked.  I'm trying to use **IMultiValueConverter** to accomplish this, but have had no luck so far.  Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
<CheckBox Name="foo"/>
<TextBlock Name="bar" Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
    <TextBlock.FontWeight>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FontConverter}">
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource self}" Path="???"/>
            <Binding ElementName="???" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.FontWeight>
</TextBlock>
```

and the converter class (just hardwired to always return bold for now)

```vb
Public Class FontConverter
    Implements IMultiValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(values() As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.Convert
        Return "Bold"
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetTypes() As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object() Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Return nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a converter you should bind to the `CheckBox.IsChecked` (`{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=foo}`), you do not need a `MultiBinding`, then in `Convert` cast the `value` to `bool` and based on that either return normal or bold (preferably as an actual `FontWeight`, not a `string`).

Here however i would recommend a [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.DataTrigger.aspx) on `IsChecked`.

e.g.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=foo}"
                             Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </DataTrigger >
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

(Also note [dependency property precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), if you set the FontWeight locally the trigger will no do anything)

Comment: Oh boo, when I wrote my answer you had an incomplete answer posted with no code sample. After posting it, I see you've updated yours to a more complete one w/ code sample. Oh well, +1 for pointing out DP precedence and for posting the same thing I did :)

Comment: @Rachel: We talked about this before, code is *not* a necessity and i am not even sure why i even added some this time. After all experience shows that people very often make errors when they try to add code (as you did here if you noticed).

Comment: @HB I did notice, thanks :) I still prefer posting code samples because I have an easier time working backwards from a code sample to figure things out, then working forwards not knowing what I'm working towards.

Comment: Egads... I just realized I didn't describe what I wanted to do well enough.  However I'll post that in a new question so as not to clutter things up here :)

Answer (score 2):

Anything based on a condition in XAML should be done in a `Trigger` or `DataTrigger`. `Converters` should be used when converting values from one value to another.

Here's an example:

```
<CheckBox Name="foo"/>
<TextBlock Name="bar" Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=foo, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```